# Unable to access post data - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, rest, api, laravel-5

I tried test the Api endpoint by get and post some data using Google Arc. The GET method works perfectly but POST method return 500 internal server error.

Here is the route:

```
Route::any('totalviews', array('as' => 'api-actionTotalviews', 'uses' => 'ApiController@actionTotalviews'));
```

Here is the controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function actionTotalviews(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();
        return $input;
    }
```

Here is the ARC post data form.[image]

Any wrong?

Comment: can you show your router here? I guess your didn't define the post router.

Comment: What is the exact error apart from 500 internal server error

Comment: Case solved. This is due to csrf token applied to all route in web config.